Homomorphism extension
The exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ (or any exponential function $x\mapsto a^x$ whatsoever, where $a>0$, $a\ne1$, is a real number) is a monomorphism from the additive group $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ of all rational numbers to the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{R}^+,\cdot)$ of all positive real numbers.
We can of course extend the domain of definition of this homomorphism to the additive group of all real numbers in the natural way, and we will then get the classical example of an isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \owns x \mapsto e^x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. But is this THE ONLY WAY to make this extension?
In other words: If $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ fulfills $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi(r)=e^r$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, must then $\phi(x)=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?
Nothing is assumed $\phi$ must be continuous, only that the algebraic structure should be  preserved.

Yes it is the only way, just use the extension theorem of uniformly continuous functions on $[-n,n]$

But it was said that continuity should NOT be required...

You wrote the converse ? Another way to prove it would be monotonicity but you don’t assume it

Don’t you have at least continuity at one point?

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $h \in \mathbb{Q}^*$
$$\frac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)}{h} = \frac{\phi(x)(\phi(h)-1)}{h} = \phi(x)\cdot \frac{e^h-1}{h}$$
Which converges to $\phi(x)$ when $h \to 0$, so $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-derivable, but not necessarily derivable and not necessarily continuous. This argument would work iff you had continuity at one point.

For $y \in x + \mathbb Q$, $\phi(y) = e^{y+c_x}$since
$$\phi(x) \phi(q) = e^{x+c_x} e^q = e^{x+q+c_x}$$

I chose $c_x = \ln (\phi(x))-x$

But if $x = y +q$ for $q \in \mathbb Q$, $c_x = c_y$ so $c$ depends on the coset $[x] \in \mathbb{R} / \mathbb Q$, so we will denote them $c([x])$.
Now notice that $c: \mathbb{R} / \mathbb Q \to \mathbb{R}$ is an additive morphism since
$$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x)\phi(y) = e^{x+c([x])}e^{y + c([y])} = e^{(x+y) + (c([x]) + c([y]))}$$
So $c([x] + [y]) =c([x+y]) = c([x]) + c([y])$.
Morphisms of this sort are uniquely determined by their value on elements of a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ which is a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space:
For simplicity, we assume that $1 \in B$. And we suppose we have a family of constants $c_b$ for $b \in B’ = B\setminus \{1\}$.

Note that any element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb Q$ is written uniquely by a linear combination of the form $\alpha = \sum_{b \in B’} q_b [b]$ since $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q} \oplus \bigoplus_{b \in B’} \mathbb{Q} \cdot b$

We define for $\alpha = \sum_{b \in B’} q_b [b]$
$$c(\alpha) = \sum_{b \in B’} q_b c_b$$
Which is of course an additive morphism.
Now let us define
$$\phi_c(x) = e^{x + c([x])}$$

For $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, $c([q]) = c(1) = \sum_{b \in B’} 0 \cdot c_b = 0$ so $\phi_c(q) = e^q$.
For $x,y \in \mathbb R$,
$$\begin{align*}
\phi_c(x+y) 
&= e^{x+y + c([x+y]) } e^{x+y + c([x]+[y]) } \\
&= e^{x+y + c([x]) +c([y]) } \\
&= e^{x+ c([x]) } e^{y + c([y]) } \\
&= \phi(x) \phi(y) \end{align*}$$
So $\mathbb{\phi_c}$ is a suitable choice.

Which means you have $\mathbb{R}^B$ choices of functions which is a cardinality of $2^\mathfrak{c}$ (the same as function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) so definitely not an unique choice.

The only « weak » and sufficient hypothesis that I know are continuity at one point of monotonicity (even at a local level).

